# Table of pointers

Tags: plc, codesys, st, wago, pfc200

I'm using Wago PLC - PFC200 - for home automation. I already did most of the things like lights or blinds automation. Recently I decided to do some refactoring and I started to think that such PLC is not a PC with a garbage collector and it might be beneficial instead of passing POU's in the table pass pointers to those POU's.

I started with something like this:

Declaration:

```
VAR
    Lighs: ARRAY [1..siTotalLightsCount] OF Relay;
END_VAR
```

where `Relay` is my POU (program organization unit - like a class).

Initialization:

```
Lighs[1] := MainLightRelay;
Lighs[2] := WindowLightRelay;
Lighs[3] := IslandLightRelay;
```

Usage in POU method:

```
FOR siCurrent := 1 TO siTotalLightsCount DO
    Lighs[siCurrent].xCentralOff := xCentralOffSignal;
END_FOR
```

But I might be beneficial to save some memory for variables and go with such an approach:

Declaration:

```
VAR
    Lighs: ARRAY [1..siTotalLightsCount] OF POINTER TO Relay;
END_VAR
```

Initialization:

```
Lighs[1] := ADR(MainLightRelay);
Lighs[2] := ADR(WindowLightRelay);
Lighs[3] := ADR(IslandLightRelay);
```

Usage in POU method:

```
FOR siCurrent := 1 TO siTotalLightsCount DO
    Lighs[siCurrent]^.xCentralOff := xCentralOffSignal;
END_FOR
```

Is that make sense? I had like 15 rooms in my home, most of the rooms has more than one light (so more `Relay` objects). It's not much, however, PLC is not PC, there are some memory constraints.

Comment: I do not think it is much improvement for such a PLC. May be one nanosecond in speed, few bytes in memory. That does not affect work. You can go either way.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use Structures and Functions instead. They would use less memory overall (as far as I know). Also, I wouldn't use Pointers to FBs (Function Blocks), but instead define Interfaces and use them to pass FBs (they work something like References, which themselves are like Pointers)

Comment: @Guiorgy I'm using interfaces for different things like room POU. I have IRoom interface which has methods to e.g.: turn off all lights. You suggest using `Lighs: ARRAY [1..siTotalLightsCount] OF IRelay` instead of `Lighs: ARRAY [1..siTotalLightsCount] OF Relay`. It seems to me that in both cases we are passing the same thing.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski, others in the [CODESYS forum](https://forge.codesys.com/forge/talk/Engineering/thread/36f763cd5b/) recommend the use of interfaces. [Here's](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.16.0/en/_cds_obj_interface/) a quote from the codesys documentation: "CODESYS always treats variables declared with the type of an interface as references". Put simply, yes, you can use both, but using pointers goes against the OOP convention. 1 thing to be aware however is, that in case of an online change, POU may be moved to new memory location. Interfaces automatically correct that!